# libssl1.1 dependency conflict on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libssl

I'm new to ubuntu and I'm trying to install nodejs npm but I get the error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1l-1ubuntu1) but 1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I tried to install libssl1.1 via apt but ig I'm doing something wrong. Please suggest me a right code to install the right version of libssl I need, I'm on Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: This is the duplicate question. Please refer to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73251468/e-package-libssl1-1-has-no-installation-candidate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [these](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions) instructions. Also it's possible libssl1.1 isn't installing on your system because you have other ssl libraries already installed and are conflicting. If they were installed from PPAs for example.